# Null pointer exception in adapter crash show in firebase analytics in production build

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, retrofit

I get null pointer exception in adapter and can't figure it out what is wrong with my code. Its working fine in test builds but in production build it give crash in firebase analytics.

Adapter code is:

```js
   
class NotificationAdapter(notificationDataArrayList:ArrayList<NotificationsData>, private val clickListener:ClickListener,
                          mcontext: Context):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.NotificationViewHolder>()
    {
        val notificationArrayList : ArrayList<NotificationsData>
        val mcontext : Context

        inner class NotificationViewHolder (itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){


            val tv_notification_title : TextView
            val tv_notification_body : TextView
//            val expandButton : ImageButton
            val expensionBody: LinearLayout

            init {
                tv_notification_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.til_request)
                tv_notification_body = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_notification_body)
//             expandButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_expand)
                expensionBody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutExpand)

            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(
            parent: ViewGroup,
            viewType: Int,
        ): NotificationViewHolder {
            val view : View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.ui_notification_item,parent,false)
            return NotificationViewHolder(view)

        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(
            holder:NotificationViewHolder,
            position: Int
        ) {
            val recyclerData : NotificationsData = notificationArrayList[position]
            holder.tv_notification_title.text = recyclerData.Title
            holder.tv_notification_body.text = recyclerData.Body
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                clickListener.onItemClick(notificationArrayList[position])

            }

        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return notificationArrayList.size
        }
        init {
            notificationArrayList = notificationDataArrayList
            this.mcontext = mcontext
        }

        interface ClickListener{
            fun onItemClick(dataModel: NotificationsData)
        }
    }
```

and I use in adapter in main fragment like :

```html
  recyclerView = binding.notificationRv.apply {
                                        adapter = NotificationAdapter(response.body()!!.Data,this@NotificationsFragmentUI,context)
                                        layoutManager = manager
                                        adapter = adapter
```

I am stuck for 2 days on this issue can't figure out how to fix it?

firebase crashlatics are:

```html
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.j.e, parameter notificationDataArrayList
com.ls.wo.sm.ui.notifications.NotificationAdapter.<init> (NotificationAdapter.kt:17)
com.ls.wo.sm.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragmentUI$notificationCall$1$onResponse$1.invoke (NotificationsFragmentUI.kt:100)
com.ls.wo.sm.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragmentUI$notificationCall$1$onResponse$1.invoke (NotificationsFragmentUI.kt:76)
com.ls.wo.sm.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragmentUI.checkIfFragmentAttached (NotificationsFragmentUI.kt:130)
com.ls.wo.sm.ui.notifications.NotificationsFragmentUI$notificationCall$1.onResponse (NotificationsFragmentUI.kt:76)
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0 (DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.$r8$lambda$hVGjmafRi6VitDIrPNdoFizVAdk (DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java)
retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$daf5173ad73a9dc0e8131143f299c222e2ca4cddd7cb10b2d0a6e331a0602ae1$0.run (DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:6)
```

Comment: The value of `response.body()!!.Data` is likely null at the point where you try to instantiate `NotificationAdapter`. Set a breakpoint there and confirm this.

Comment: @Gavin not working right.

Comment: Just as @GavinWright said, if the data received is `null` then a crash is going to happen. However, you can cross-check this in the `init` block itself & also initialize the `notificationDataArrayList` by default.